# bootstrap submenu not working locally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So what I'm trying to do is add sub menus to my main dropdown as it is shown in http://www.bootply.com/3gl49Mdq4p# or here under the sub menus bit http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns I can't figure out why is my code not working.

When I hover the "TVs" bit from the dropdown another dropdown list consisting of "Remote controls", "Projectors" and "Flat Screen" should pop up but it just doesn't even though I've tried doing it as it says in both sources...

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
     <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#" data-toggle = "dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">TVs</a>                      
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Remote Controls</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Flat Screen</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Projectors</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>                     
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You code seems to work: http://www.bootply.com/xg8u6O6W7y - Are you using any other code or getting any errors?

Comment: Hmm, no. I tried this with my full code and it did work... So this seems to be an issue when I run it locally...

Comment: You can post your full code in a JsFiddle if you want - my only other thought without seeing anything is to check for any syntax errors in your <script> tags and see if you're getting any errors in the console.

Comment: There's not much to it except all of the meta and script stuff since I'm just trying stuff out http://pastebin.com/RQ8BPfqc

Comment: Everything in your code looks like it should work - the only thing I can't see is your CSS - and it will not work without the css, so i would say just make sure that it is in your style.css. See my fiddle with your code, and the correct css: http://jsfiddle.net/eFdtb/1/